# Thread Synchronization in Django

Tags: python, django, synchronized

Is there any way to block a critical area like with Java synchronized in Django?

Comment: In many cases, doing something like Java's `synchronized` is not good enough for Django code. The usual scenario in a Django app is not to just protect a resource from *other threads* but from *any code that will try to use the resource*. In many cases, a WSGI server will use multiple *processes* to serve requests and thus you need to prevent not only other *threads* in a single process from accessing the resource but all *processes* that may try to access it. `synchronized` is not good enough for this and a Python solution that replicates what `synchronized` does won't be good enough either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use locks to make sure that only one Thread will access a certain block of code at a time.

To do this, you simply create a `Lock` object then acquire the lock before the block of code you want to synchronize. All the threads must have access to the same `Lock` object for this to work. An example:

```py
from threading import Lock, Thread

lock = Lock()

def do_something():
    lock.acquire()   # will block if another thread has lock
    try:
        # ... use lock
    finally:
        lock.release()

Thread(target=do_something).start()
Thread(target=do_something).start()
```

For more information , see [http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20201101025814/http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm).

Comment: As Louis commented on the question, this will only work if there is a single server process, which is often not the case.

Answer (score 4):

My approach is to use the locking features of the database. This also works with multiple server processes.

I define a model as:

```
from django.db import models

class ThreadSafe(models.Model):
    key = m.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
```

And then a context manager function as:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from django.db.transaction import atomic

@contextmanager
def lock(key):
    pk = ThreadSafe.objects.get_or_create(key=key)[0].pk
    try:
        objs = ThreadSafe.objects.filter(pk=pk).select_for_update()
        with atomic():
            list(objs)
            yield None
    finally:
        pass
```

And then I have a thread/process safe lock by simply doing:

```
with lock("my_key"):
    do_scary_stuff_here()
```

This requires a database with support for transactions.

Comment: The advantage with this approach is that this lock is shared by all processes (and all database connections) that connect to this database. But you pay a performance cost.

Answer (score 0):

Great article Justin, just one thing using python 2.5 makes this way easier

In Python 2.5 and later, you can also use the with statement. When used with a lock, this statement automatically acquires the lock before entering the block, and releases it when leaving the block:

from **future** import with_statement # 2.5 only

with lock:
    ... access shared resource

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you could use advisory locks. Any process or thread could acquire or release this lock, assuming they are all connecting to the same PostgreSQL database.  [`django-pglocks`](https://pypi.org/project/django-pglocks/) takes this approach.