# Save to django session in middle of a view

Tags: ajax, django, session

I'm sending an AJAX request every time the user checked an input.
The request activates a user_input() view, and user's choice is added to the session. Later on at the view, I'll use the user's inputs to update an algorithm.

The problem is, when a user clicks two inputs in a row (in less then a second between clicks), only one choice is saved to the session. I believe it's happening because the session is saved only after the view is done. I would like to save the session immediately, so it would be available to the second view (activated by the second AJAX).

`request.session.modified = True` is not helping.

`request.session.save()` should have resolve the problem (http://kechengpuzi.com/q/s13748166), but unfortunately its not working..

views.py:

```
def user_input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session.modified = True
        object_id = request.POST.get('object_id')
        request.session['user_input'].append(int(object_id))
        request.session.save()
        print('input checked. ', request.session['inputs_list'])
        return HttpResponse(response_data,content_type="application/json")
    else:
        return HttpResponse(failed_data, content_type="application/json")
```

**input:**

1

2

3 4 (choose again, without waiting for response)

**output:**

intput checked. [1]

intput checked. [1,2]

intput checked. [1,2,3]

intput checked. [1,2,4] (I need it to be [1,2,3,4])

I'm using Django 3.4 develepment server, 
 python 3.4, 
 django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware session engine, 
and mysql database

Comment: You could block the input for an certain amount of time. It's not a nice solution though...

Comment: Are you testing against the Django development server (manage.py runserver)? AFAIK it's single threaded and should block anyway. It might also be helpful to consider your config... session engine, database (session engine default is the database), and transaction/autocommit mode?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. yes, I'm using Django develepment server. 
session engine: django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware, 
database: sqlite, 
python 3.4, 
django 1.8, 
Never used (or heard :)) the transaction/autocommit mode.

By saying block, do you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534943/thread-synchronization-in-django 
?
if so, how can I block the view?
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because request object coming from each ajax call is different.
I would suggest to declare a global variable and store the first request in it and then use this variable to set session rather than "request" object.

```
ajax_request = None
def user_input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not ajax_request:
            ajax_request = request
        object_id = request.POST.get('object_id')
        ajax_request.session['user_input'].append(int(object_id))
        ajax_request.session.save()
        print('input checked. ', ajax_request.session['inputs_list'])
        return HttpResponse(response_data,content_type="application/json")
    else:
        return HttpResponse(failed_data, content_type="application/json")
```